# Travel Time from Ruby Geocoder Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-geocoder

I'm wondering if the Geocoder Gem for Ruby has any way of getting travel time information along with the distance? Some of the APIs it relies on /do/ provide this information, so I'm wondering if there's any way to retrieve that from the response.

Comment: if you know the distance that difficult in calculating the time? Geocoder gem create for geocoding coordinates, distance queries. It is just wrapper around some providers like Google, Yandex, Bing, e.t.c. I think it's more about [Google directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).

Comment: I mean I could blindly enter a speed like 30mph and get a rough estimate but Google Maps and Co tend to be more accurate than that, taking into account traffic and other matters. If it's a wrapper around Google's API, that's why I think this information *might* be available, since the Maps API does provide it.

Comment: Did you get it work?